Issue in connecting the MariaDB using MaxScale
I am trying to  connect to MariaDB using  below approach using the service name for MaxScale here:
 kubectl run mariadb --rm -it --image=mariadb:10.6 -- bash -c "mariadb  -h mariadb-galera-maxscale.default.svc.cluster.local  -P3306 -u mariadb -p'xxxxxxx'"

Where 3306:32000 is the port exposed for maxscale service.
But, i am always getting below error:
error: timed out waiting for the condition

pod log
kubectl logs mariadb
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mariadb'@'10.244.0.97' (using password: YES)

maxscale pod is running:
kubectl get pods -A| grep maxscale
default              mariadb-galera-maxscale-0                          1/1     Running   0             10m

Service  yaml used is here
kubectl describe svc mariadb-galera-maxscale                                                                            
Name:                     mariadb-galera-maxscale
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              metallb.universe.tf/loadBalancerIPs: 172.18.0.229
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=mariadb-galera-maxscale,app.kubernetes.io/name=maxscale
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack


 Warning  AllocationFailed  100s  metallb-controller  Failed to allocate IP for "default/mariadb-galera-maxscale": ["172.18.0.229"] is not allowed in config

Please Help.
Is there any other way to use the service name of MaxScale to connect to MariaDB?

This sounds related to how the k8s is configured. Can you include a config for that in your question by editing the question. Also confirm the logs of the the maxscale pod should show it running.

@danblack Updated. Please let me know if you need more info.
